# How to reduce the height of the text!

Tags: formatting

I want to reduce the length of the text a bit to cover more pages

I am using a \documentclass{these}, it is defined in a (.cls)-file that my advisor sent to me, this (.cls)-file is given as follows:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\ProvidesClass{these}[2007/07/16 classe pour mise en forme de These]
\LoadClass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage[includefoot,nomarginpar,twoside,
    top=27mm,bottom=27mm,
    head=5mm,headsep=7mm,
    footskip=7mm,
    hmargin=25mm,bindingoffset=10mm]{geometry}

\newif\if@blankemptypage
\DeclareOption{noblankemptypage}{\@blankemptypagefalse}
\DeclareOption{blankemptypage}{\@blankemptypagetrue}

\@blankemptypagefalse
%\ExecuteOptions{}
\ProcessOptions

% names
\newcommand{\@titleapp}{Titre}
\newcommand{\@engtitleapp}{Title}
\newcommand{\@resumeapp}{R\'esum\'e}
\newcommand{\@abstractapp}{Abstract}
\newcommand{\@keywordsapp}{Mot-clefs}
\newcommand{\@engkeywordsapp}{Keywords}
\newcommand{\@juryapp}{Jury}
\newcommand{\@advisorapp}{Directeur de th\`ese }
\newcommand{\@coadvisorapp}{Co-directeur de th\`ese}
\newcommand{\@labapp}{Laboratoire}

% Sets the name of the laboratory
\newcommand{\@labo}{\textbf{!\texttt{labo} \`a d\'efinir!}}
\newcommand{\labo}[1]{\renewcommand{\@labo}{#1}}

% Sets the name of the school
\newcommand{\@school}{\textbf{!\texttt{school} \`a d\'efinir!}}
\newcommand{\school}[1]{\renewcommand{\@school}{#1}}

% Sets the name of the phd speciality
\newcommand{\@speciality}{\textbf{!\texttt{speciality} \`a d\'efinir!}}
\newcommand{\speciality}[1]{\renewcommand{\@speciality}{#1}}

% Sets the name of the university
\newcommand{\@universityabbrv}{\textbf{!\texttt{universit\'e} \`a d\'efinir!}}
\newcommand{\@university}{\textbf{!\texttt{universit'e} \`a d\'efinir!}}
\newcommand{\university}[2]{
    \renewcommand{\@universityabbrv}{#1}
    \renewcommand{\@university}{#2}
}

% Sets the ISBN number (if not set, prints lines for space to the 10 digits to
% be written
\newlength{\@ISBNcolwidth}
\setlength{\@ISBNcolwidth}{.25em}
\newcommand{\@ISBN}{
    \begin{tabular}{*{13}{|p{\@ISBNcolwidth}}|}
        &&&&&&&&&\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\newcommand{\ISBN}[1]{\renewcommand{\@ISBN}{\texttt{#1}}}

% Sets the advisor name (and title, optional, defaults to M)
\newcommand{\@advisor}{\textbf{!\texttt{advisor} \`a d\'efinir!}}
\newcommand{\@advisortitle}{M}
\newcommand{\advisor}[2][M]{
    \renewcommand{\@advisortitle}{#1}
    \renewcommand{\@advisor}{#2}
}
    
% Sets the coadvisor name (and title, optional, defaults to M)
\newcommand{\@coadvisor}{\textbf{!\texttt{coadvisor} \`a d\'efinir!}}
\newcommand{\@coadvisortitle}{M}
\newcommand{\coadvisor}[2][M]{
    \renewcommand{\@coadvisortitle}{#1}
    \renewcommand{\@coadvisor}{#2}
}

% Defines a member of the jury
\newcommand{\@jury}{}
\newcommand{\jury}[1]{\renewcommand{\@jury}{
\begin{tabular}{r@{ }ll}
#1
\end{tabular}
}}
\newcommand{\jurymember}[3][M]{#1. &#2, &#3}
\newcommand{\juryadvisor}[1][Directeur de th\`ese]{
    \jurymember[\@advisortitle]{\@advisor}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\jurycoadvisor}[1][Co-directeur de th\`ese]{
    \jurymember[\@coadvisortitle]{\@coadvisor}{#1}
}

\newcommand{\@labaddr}{}
\newcommand{\labaddr}[1]{
    \renewcommand{\@labaddr}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\@engtitle}{}
\newcommand{\engtitle}[1]{
    \renewcommand{\@engtitle}{#1}
}

\newcommand{\@resume}{}
\newcommand{\@abstract}{}
\newcommand{\resume}[2]{
    \renewcommand{\@resume}{#1}
    \renewcommand{\@abstract}{#2}
    \chapter{\@resumeapp}
    \@resume

    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@abstract}{}}{}{
        \@openrightfalse
        \chapter{\@abstractapp}
        \@openrighttrue
        \@abstract
    }
}

\newcommand{\@keywords}{}
\newcommand{\@engkeywords}{}
\newcommand{\keywords}[2]{
    \renewcommand{\@keywords}{#1}
    \renewcommand{\@engkeywords}{#2}
}

\newcommand{\@resumesize}{\small}
\newcommand{\resumesize}[1]{\renewcommand{\@resumesize}{#1}}
    
% redefine the \maketitle command
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \begin{titlepage}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
%\geometry{nomarginpar,noheadfoot,twoside,showframe,
%    top=15mm,bottom=20mm,
%    hmargin=25mm,bindingoffset=10mm}
%        \vsize = 277mm
%        \voffset = -15mm
%        \topmargin = 0mm
%        \headheight = 0mm
%        \headsep = 0mm
%        \hsize = 160mm
%        \hoffset = -10mm
%        \vbox to \vsize {
            \begin{center}
                \textsc{\@university}
            \end{center}
            \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
            \begin{flushright}
                \parbox{6cm}{
                   % \begin{center}
                    %    N{$^\circ$} attribu\'e par la biblioth\`eque\\
                     %   \texttt{\@ISBN}
                    %\end{center}
                }
            \end{flushright}
            \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
            \begin{center}
                {\Large\textbf{TH\`ESE}}\\
                \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
                pour obtenir le grade de\\
                \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
                \textbf{\textsc{Docteur} de \@universityabbrv}\\
                \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
                Sp\'ecialit\'e : \textbf{\@speciality}\\
                \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
                pr\'epar\'ee au laboratoire \textbf{\@labo}\\
                \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
                dans le cadre de l'\'Ecole Doctorale \textbf{\@school}\\
                \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
                pr\'esent\'ee et soutenue publiquement\\
                par\\
                \vspace*{\stretch{3}}
                {\Large\textbf{\@author}}\\
                \vspace*{\stretch{3}}
                le \@date\\
                \vspace*{\stretch{5}}
                \@titleapp :\\
                {\large\textbf{\@title}}\\
                \vspace*{\stretch{5}}
                \@advisorapp : \textbf{\@advisor}\\
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\@coadvisor}{}}{}{
                    \@coadvisorapp : \textbf{\@coadvisor}\\
                }
                \vspace*{\stretch{8}}
                {\large \@juryapp}\\
                \@jury
            \end{center}
%        }
    \end{titlepage}
}

% Back page
\newcommand{\@backsection}[5][r]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{%
    }{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\noindent\textbf{\textsc{#2}}%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{r}}{\\}{}}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{r}}{\indent}{\noindent}{#4{#3}}\\%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{r}}{%
            \vspace*{\stretch{1}}%
            \noindent\rule{\hsize}{1pt}%
            \vspace*{\stretch{1}}%
        }{}%
     }%
}
\newcommand{\makeback}{
    \begin{titlepage}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \null\clearpage
        \thispagestyle{empty}
%        \vsize = 277mm
%        \voffset = -15mm
%        \topmargin = 0mm
%        \headheight = 0mm
%        \headsep = 0mm
%        \hsize = 160mm
%        \hoffset = -10mm
%        \vbox to \vsize {
            \noindent\rule{\hsize}{1pt}
            \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
            \@backsection{\@resumeapp}{\@resume}{\@resumesize}
            \@backsection{\@keywordsapp}{\@keywords}{\@resumesize}
            \@backsection{\@engtitleapp}{\@title}{\bf}
            \@backsection{\@abstractapp}{\@abstract}{\@resumesize}
            \@backsection{\@engkeywordsapp}{\@engkeywords}{\@resumesize}
            \@backsection[]{Adrr : }{\@labaddr}{\@resumesize}%
            \@backsection[]{ISBN : }{\@ISBN}{}
%            \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
%            \noindent\textbf{\textsc{ISBN}} : {\@resumesize{\@ISBN}}
%            \noindent\textbf{\textsc{ISBN}} : {\@resumesize{\@ISBN}}
    \end{titlepage}
}

% fancy pagestyle redefinition
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\small\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[LO,C,RE]{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\rm\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\small\rightmark}
    \fancyfoot[C]{}
% plain pagestyle redefinition
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead[L,C,R]{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\rm\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[LO,C,RE]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand\thepart           {\@Roman\c@part}
\renewcommand\thechapter        {\@arabic\c@chapter}
\renewcommand\thesection        {\@arabic\c@section}
\renewcommand\thesubsection     {\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection  {\thesubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsection}
\renewcommand\theparagraph      {\thesubsubsection.\@arabic\c@paragraph}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph   {\theparagraph.\@arabic\c@subparagraph}

\newcommand{\openany}{\@openrightfalse}
\newcommand{\openright}{\@openrighttrue}

\newif{\if@frontmatter}
\renewcommand{\frontmatter}{
    \cleardoublepage
    \@mainmatterfalse
    \@frontmattertrue
    \pagenumbering{roman}}
\renewcommand{\mainmatter}{
    \cleardoublepage
    \@mainmattertrue
    \@frontmatterfalse
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
}
\renewcommand{\backmatter}{
    \if@openright
        \cleardoublepage
    \else
        \clearpage
    \fi
    \@mainmatterfalse
    \@frontmatterfalse
}

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
            \refstepcounter{chapter}
            \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}
            {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}
        \else
            \if@frontmatter
                \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
            \else
                \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{toto#1}
            \fi
        \fi
    \else
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
    \fi
    \chaptermark{#1}
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}
    \if@twocolumn
        \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]
    \else
        \@makechapterhead{#2}
        \@afterheading
    \fi
}

\let\@oldschapter\@schapter
\def\@schapter#1{%
    \@oldschapter{#1}%
    \if@mainmatter
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{{#1}}
    \else
        \if@frontmatter
            \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
        \else
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
        \fi
    \fi
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
}

\if@blankemptypage
    %Redefine cleardoublepage so that the pages inserted are really empty
    \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
        \clearpage
        \if@twoside
            \ifodd
                \c@page
            \else
                \null
                \thispagestyle{empty} %set style empty
                \newpage
                \if@twocolumn\null\newpage\fi
            \fi
        \fi
    }
\fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change some of the lengths in the call to the `geometry` package.

`top` and `bottom` refer to the space above and below the textblock. `hmargin` refers to the margins to the left and right of the textblock. Increasing any of these will reduce the size of the textblock and so the same number of words will require an increased number of pages.

Comment: thank you very much, it works!

Comment: Peter Wilson: i want to post an other question, but i said that may be you have the answer: the margin on the right and on the left are not equal, and this page by page for example:

Comment: page 5: the margin on the right greater than on the left  \\


page 6: the margin on the left greater than on the right

and vice versa

Comment: i want that there the page stays as well in the middel and this for all pages !! i want that they stay  aligned